# Speed of loading files with asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm writing a piece of code that needs to compare a python set to many other sets and retain the names of the files which have a minimum intersection length. I currently have a synchronous version but was wondering if it could benefit from async/await. I wanted to start by comparing the loading of sets. I wrote a simple script that writes a small set to disk and just reads it in *n* amount of times. I was suprised to see the sync version of this was a lot faster. Is this to be expected? and if not is there a flaw in the way I have coded it below?

My code is the following:

Synchronous version:

```
import pickle
import asyncio
import time 
import aiofiles

pickle.dump(set(range(1000)), open('set.pkl', 'wb'))

def count():
    print("Started Loading")
    with open('set.pkl', mode='rb') as f:
        contents = pickle.loads(f.read())
    print("Finishd Loading")

def main():
    for _ in range(100):
        count()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = time.perf_counter()
    main()
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f"{__file__} executed in {elapsed:0.3f} seconds.")
```

Asynchronous version:

```
import pickle
import asyncio
import time 
import aiofiles

pickle.dump(set(range(1000)), open('set.pkl', 'wb'))

async def count():
    print("Started Loading")
    async with aiofiles.open('set.pkl', mode='rb') as f:
        contents = pickle.loads(await f.read())
    print("Finishd Loading")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*(count() for _ in range(100)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    s = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f"{__file__} executed in {elapsed:0.3f} seconds.")
```

Execuitng them led to:

```
async.py executed in 0.052 seconds.
sync.py executed in 0.011 seconds.
```

Comment: You said the async version is faster, as it should be, but your posted times are indicating that async was 5 times slower.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy sorry I meant to say that the sync was faster. I've edited that now.

Comment: I've been working a lot with async lately, and by observation, it only seems to be a game-changer for numerous asynchronous http requests. My app currently gets a feed and then scrapes every page in the feed items so, in the long run it ends up making about 100 requests per feed. It's capped right now at max 4 async feeds. Now we're at potentially 400 requests. Async shines in this scenario. I personally haven't found a local request that is "heavy" enough to require async.

Comment: You have only one file.  It is written to a storage device of some sort.  When you open and read that file, the device on which it is stored has to access a specific piece of data, at a specific location.  That will be a physical bottleneck.  I don't see how reading the same file 100 times can possibly happen in parallel, and I wouldn't expect any sort of speedup.  I think the slow-down that you observe is the overhead of launching 100 asyncio Tasks, and forcing them to thrash back and forth as they encounter await expressions.  This is not a good test concept.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Ah right thanks for the info, that saves me doing all the testing myself!

Comment: @PaulCornelius Ok yeah that makes sense, not an ideal test. In the real scenario it would be reading in lot of different files and doing other operations when it has read them in. My initial thoughts were that maybe while it is waiting on the disk for some to load it could start processing ones it had already loaded. But based on the answers so far it looks that isn't the case.

Comment: "But based on the answers so far it looks that isn't the case" ~ I wouldn't be so quick to discount it entirely. This is what I would suggest: Make your app without async, and if it ever gets to a point where things seem unreasonably slow, change your loader to be async. If you make your thing with this possible change in mind you could design it to where you basically just need to put `async` and `await` a few places, and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Asyncio doesn’t help in this case because your workload is basically disk-IO bound and CPU bound.

CPU bound workload cannot be sped up by Asyncio.

Disk-IO bound workload could benefit from async operation if but the disk operation is very slow and your program can do other things during that time.  This may not be your situation.

So the slower asyncio performance is mainly due to the additional overhead introduced.

Answer (score 0):

aiofiles is implemented by using threads, so each time you tell it to read a file another thread will be instructed to read the file.

the file being read is actually very small it fits in 3 KB which is under 1 page in your memory and also smaller than your core L1 cache, the computer didn't actually read anything from the disk most of the time, it's all being moved between parts of your memory.

in the async case it is being moved from one core's memory to the second, which is slower than keeping everything within 1 core's cache, but for larger files that are actually read from disk and other tasks to attend to, such as reading from sockets and reading different files from disk and doing some processing concurrently you will find the async version is faster, because it is using threads under the hood, and some tasks drop the gil, like reading from files and sockets, and some processing libraries.

you are still reading files at the same speed in both cases as you will be limited by your drive read speed, you will only be reducing the "dead-time" of when you are not reading files, and your example has no "dead-time", it isn't even reading a file from disk.

an exception to the above happens when you are reading data from multiple HDDs and SSDs concurrently where 1 thread can never read the data fast enough so the async version will be faster, because it can read from multiple drives at the same time (assuming you have the cores and IO lanes for it in your CPU)

Comment: Per core CPU cache will almost never, be something that will make _any_ difference in Python code. Everything runs several layers apart from the machine. In this code, for example, the file contents are passed to `pickle.loads` which will perform high level object creation - very, very, very far away from the "3Kb < a 4KB mesmory page")

Comment: @jsbueno set.pkl file is still entirely cashed into memory by the operating system, the computer doesn't read anything from disk, and the page should remain in the L1/L2 caches of any recent processor, and i have run benchmarks on the impact of core cache on python code before, it's not as heavy as the 200 times you get from C++, more like a factor of 10.